# Is it possible that reading from a registry read prevents a COM server from starting?

Tags: delphi, com, registry

I've got some code that basically calls `CreateComObject(...)` after checking the registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\...\LocalServer32` is valid.

The problem is: The COM server only loads correctly when I don't check the registry key.

How is that possible?

```
const
  csLibGuid                 : TGUID  = '...';
  csLibMd5Sum               : string = '...';
  csLibRegKeyFormatRegular  : string = '\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\%s\LocalServer32';
  csLibRegKeyFormatWow64    : string = '\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%s\LocalServer32';
  csLibClassName            : string = '...';

procedure TLibLoader.CheckLibraryChecksum;
var
  FileNames  : TStringList;
  Registry   : TRegistry;

  procedure AddFileName(AHKEY: HKEY; const AFormat: string);
  begin
    Registry.RootKey := AHKEY;
    Registry.OpenKey(
        Format(AFormat, [GUIDToString(csLibGuid)])
      , False
    );
    try
      FileName := Registry.ReadString(csEmpty);
      if Trim(FileName) > csEmpty then begin
        FileNames.Add(FileName);
      end;
    finally
      Registry.CloseKey;
    end;
  end;

var
  FileName   : string;
  FileDigest : string;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_EXECUTE);
  try
    FileNames := TStringList.Create;
    try
      FileNames.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
      FileNames.Sorted     := True;
      AddFileName(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csLibRegKeyFormatRegular);
      AddFileName(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csLibRegKeyFormatWoW64);
      AddFileName(HKEY_CURRENT_USER , csLibRegKeyFormatRegular);
      AddFileName(HKEY_CURRENT_USER , csLibRegKeyFormatWoW64);
      if FileNames.Count = 0 then begin
        raise EProtector.Create('All registry keys are empty');
      end;
      for FileName in FileNames do begin
        if not FileExists(FileName) then begin
          raise Exception.Create(Format('File "%s" does not exist', [FileName]));
        end;
        FileDigest := TMD5.HashFile(FileName);
        if not AnsiSameText(FileDigest, csLibMd5Sum) then begin
          raise Exception.Create(Format('File "%s" is not valid', [FileName]));
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FileNames.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;

CheckLibraryChecksum;
CreateComObject(csLibGuid);
```

Comment: As an aside, I'm not leen on your string comparison. You use `Trim(FileName) > csEmpty` which I find rather opaque. I expect that `csEmpty` is the same as `''`. You should be using `<>` to compare here. I agree that it gives exactly the same results, but your are not interested in ordering, you are interesting in whether or not the file name is empty. I also suggest that you use some form of logging to find out exactly what is causing your COM server to fail. This will pay dividends in the future.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The `csEmpty` is company policy to avoid confusion of `''` and `' '`. Sadly I don't have the source code for the COM server which makes debugging more difficult.

Comment: I can understand that. Of course, the RTL comes with `EmptyStr` already.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: whaa. How long has that been around and have I missed that?

Comment: @MarjanVenema Been around forever. Not that I use it. I much prefer `''`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Me too, I just sometimes regret not having/taking the time to delve deeper into RTL/VCL changes when upgrading, because if you don't you can miss some very handy additions.

Comment: The real problem turns out to be something entirely different: There is no `FileName` variable in the subprocedure `AddFileName`, so the code is setting a property of the '`LibLoader` class called `FileName` which leads to some evil side effects ...

Comment: @Jens - Thanks for telling the real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of `OpenKey`. You must do so, and only go on to read values if `OpenKey` returns `True`.

I suspect that some of these keys do not exist. You then ignore the `False` that comes back from `OpenKey` and try to read a value anyway. That will lead to exceptions being raised.

So your function should be like so:

```
procedure AddFileName(AHKEY: HKEY; const AFormat: string);
begin
  Registry.RootKey := AHKEY;
  if Registry.OpenKey(
      Format(AFormat, [GUIDToString(csLibGuid)])
    , False
  ) then begin
    try
      FileName := Registry.ReadString(csEmpty);
      if Trim(FileName) > csEmpty then begin
        FileNames.Add(FileName);
      end;
    finally
      Registry.CloseKey;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Personally I'd use `OpenKeyReadOnly` because I feel it is more explicit. I realise that you are using `KEY_EXECUTE` as your `Access` value which is the same as `KEY_READ`. I just feel that `OpenKeyReadOnly` makes it easier for the human reader to verify intent.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, I will change the code accordingly. I guess I'll have to come up with a better test project to understand my problem better. Maybe I'll write a followup question on this issue.

Comment: BTW: It's interesting that KEY_READ and KEY_EXECUTE are really the same value, but have different descriptions in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.Access

Comment: MSDN says of 'KEY_EXECUTE': `Equivalent to KEY_READ`. I guess the `SYNCHRONIZE` is not applicable to registry keys any more. Perhaps it was once upon a time.

Comment: It is also important to use `OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead of `OpenKey()` when you are only reading from the key because `OpenKeyReadOnly()` internally tries several combinations of permissions until it finds one that succeeds (in case the app is running as a Standard User vs an Admin), and then sets the `TRegistry.Access` property to the value that actually worked. `OpenKey()` just uses the current `TRegistry.Access` property value as-is, so you have to make sure it is set correctly beforehand.